# Youtube Player API hide controls, hide info, hide related videos?

Tags: api, youtube

I am trying to load a Youtube video in the home page (Chromeless) useing JavaScript API.
So far I managed to make it auto play, hd720 and fadeOut the video once it is finished.

But I can't find a way to remove controls, hide info and not to load related video at the end.

I know in iframe embed I can use below parameters

```
controls=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&rel=0
```

But I can't find way to use these parameters in YouTube Player API shown below.
Any suggestion?

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api?enablejsapi=1&version=3"></script>

  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('video_chromeless', {
                height: '800',
                width: '450',
                videoId: '',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
        }
function onPlayerReady(event){
            player.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
            event.target.playVideo();
        }
 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if(event.data === 0) {
                $('#video_chromeless').fadeOut(600);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As of September 25, 2018 we do not have the ability to hide related videos

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can set 'playerVars' in the second parameter of "YT.Player":
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

Comment: Can you change the player vars dynamically?  I want to be able to hide the controls by default but then be able to expose them if the user clicks a button.

Comment: @asutherland, did you find an answer for that?
I am struggling to hide/show controls programatically.

Comment: I did not, I ended up building my own custom controls, but I haven't worked on that bit code code in a year or two so there may be a better option today.

Answer (score 25):

This works fine for me:

```
player = new YT.Player('divId', {
    videoId : videoSrc,
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 1, 
        'rel' : 0,
        'fs' : 0,
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work (2022)

Answer (score 5):

YouTube updated their policy.
After September 25, 2018, "showinfo" parameter is deprecated and ignored from iframe.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018

Comment: alternatives .?

Answer (score 0):

According to the latest policy update of YouTube, we will no longer be able to hide the related videos using `rel:0` flag.

[you can see the rel flag got changed from 25th sept 2018](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDJiA.png)

[You can refer to this link for latest parameters of YouTubeAPI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

To hide the controls

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'nYAsTBpyWto',
          playerVars: {
            controls: 0,
            disablekb: 1
          },
...
```