# Stopping Suggested Videos At End Of My YouTube Video

Tags: video, youtube, ads

Is there a way to opt out, even "buy my way out" of having suggested videos that appear at the end of MY videos?

We have private videos which are embedded on our site and are willing to pay to stop suggested videos if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube Player API hide controls, hide info, hide related videos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900442/youtube-player-api-hide-controls-hide-info-hide-related-videos)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `?rel=0` after your Youtube ID

For Example:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Source:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel