# JQuery: No Controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

How do I get rid of all controls on the Youtube Player so that when it loads all I can do is click the video to pause. To help understand what I mean: https://www.kanyewest.com/ exactly like this. Please comment if you are unsure what I mean

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '1000',
      width: '1905',
      videoId: 'a5SMyfbWYyE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}

// autoplay video
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// when video ends
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
        alert('done');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Player API hide controls, hide info, hide related videos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900442/youtube-player-api-hide-controls-hide-info-hide-related-videos)

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `playerVars` property on the object that you're passing to `YT.Player`. On the `playerVars` object, you'll need to set the `controls` property to zero.

Here is how I did it on a recent project:

[Code](https://github.com/tcoughlin3/playlist/blob/master/client/js/video.js)

[App](http://the-playlist.herokuapp.com/)

```
  //Instantiate new YouTube player after iFrame API has loaded
  $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: {
        'autohide': 1,
        'modestbranding': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'iv_load_policy': 3,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'color': 'white'
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Relevant documentation:

[YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5)

[Controls parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#controls)