# Youtube Iframe API - Hide HUD

Tags: javascript, youtube, background, youtube-iframe-api, hud

Is there any way to remove/hide any HUD/control element from the Youtube Iframe?

I've tried so many things like almost every combination of playerVars/query options and I've also tried to edit the Iframe document even if I already knew it wouldn't work.

I've searched for a solution in these two StackOverflow questions but nothing worked:

- [Youtube Player API hide controls, hide info, hide related videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900442/youtube-player-api-hide-controls-hide-info-hide-related-videos?rq=1)
- [Can you hide the controls of a YouTube embed without enabling autoplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710764/can-you-hide-the-controls-of-a-youtube-embed-without-enabling-autoplay)

It seems like Youtube has removed this possibility.

My goal is to have a Youtube video as background for a webpage.

So is there any workaround or alternative so I can use a Youtube video as my webpage background?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example for you, using the youtube API, with the maximum discretion options I know.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYwMGd

Here is the secret to control the youtube player.

```
playerVars: {
  'autoplay': 1,
  'controls': 0,
  'disablekb': 1,
  'fs': 0,
  'loop': 1,
  'modestbranding': 1,
  'rel': 0,
  'showinfo': 0,
  'mute': 1,
  'autohide': 1
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the result I actually have... I should have included it in my question. Though, in my opinion it's a little weird to have a Youtube with HUD/controls slowly fading out as a webpage background

Comment: You have 2 alternatives:
- Show the video after the controls disappear
- Serve the video in its own environment

Comment: If I can't find any solution I will probably add an effect on page load like a zoom out effect so the controls in the corners have enough time to disappear before they fit within the window/container borders or something like that